# listing primary keys from data dictionary

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am working on a team that is responsible for data replication to the new database.

For the scripts we need to copy every single primary key in the schema to the scripts. Now this isn't difficult just time consuming to access each table and get the PK.

Is there a way to dynamically list all the PK's from the datadictionary to speed up this process?

Comment: What do you mean by "copy every single primary key in the schema to the scripts?"  I'm not following what you're trying to do.  Can you share a bit of your code?

Comment: I actually cannot share this script. I'll try to explain as best as I can. Essentially i'm in a position where I would have to copy and past every primary key from every table into a script we're running that replicates our dev database to the production database. Rather then manually looking at each table and it's primary key I would just to like list all the primary keys in our dev database ( possibly from the data dictionary) so I can easily insert them into our script. I'm sorry id this isn't descriptive enough. It sucks that I can't share the script. Was that helpful at all?

Comment: Somewhat - I guess the better question is, what are you trying to do with the data?  Are you migrating records from the dev environment to production?  If so, you may want to consider using a tool designed for that, such as SSIS.

Comment: When you say "primary key" do you mean "the columns that make up the primary key in the table definition" or "the values of the primary key columns for every row of data"?

Comment: Yes, were migrating all objects from dev to production. The catch about external tools is the company I work for is very strict regarding third party tools. Since we license all the software we use. Currently were using pl/sql scripts to automate the migration process. I'm a beginner so excuse the fact that I'm still learning industry vocabulary.

Comment: @rhys jones I'm speaking to the columns that make the primary key not the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be close to what you are looking for.  There is more information you could include if you wanted from `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` or `DBA_CONS_COLUMNS`.

```
SELECT c.owner,
       c.constraint_name,
       c.table_name,
       c.status,
       LISTAGG (cc.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cc.position) key_columns
FROM   dba_constraints c
       INNER JOIN dba_cons_columns cc
         ON cc.owner = c.owner
         AND cc.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
         AND cc.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE  c.constraint_type = 'P'
GROUP BY c.owner,
         c.constraint_name,
         c.table_name,
         c.status
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wrote out this script but am receiving an empty data grid any idea why that may be? Also thanks Matthew, you've helped me on previous questions and it's appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Try the usual debugging techniques.  I.e. try a wide-open `SELECT * FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS` and see if you get data.  Then try to add `WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'` and see if you get data, etc.  If you mean the data grid has rows but they're all empty, try it in SQL*Plus.